# Data lost on refresh in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am redirecting a page like this:

```
return redirect('vendor/vendors')->with('vendor', $allvendors);
```

and getting it from Blade template like this:

```
@foreach($vendor as $vendors)
```

but it's not working or at times when it loads, and I refresh the page, it will give error like the data has been deleted:

```
Undefined variable: vendor (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/easyhire-web/resources/views/vendor/vendors.blade.php)
```

Comment: Why would you expect that variable to be defined on a refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `with` method on the redirect response is meant for passing [flashed session data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data). That data does not persist, so if you code your view to expect that data to be present on every request it will fail on normal page loads.

Any data that you *need* should be retrieved in the controller action that corresponds to the URL you are redirecting to.